# How to make a dialog(view) open up on the same monitor as the main window

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, window, multiple-monitors

In a PC with multiple monitors, say you run your application which have have a second Window/Dialog other than the main window (such as Options) that you want it to open in the same screen/monitor as your `MainWindow`. How to force this behavior?

You basically want to stop the scenario that your `MainWindow` is on one monitor and when you bring up the "Options" page, it shows on a different screen/monitor.

Comment: It may just be too late in the day, but I don't understand your question. Could you try rephrasing it or posting a sketch of what you're trying to do?

Comment: @goobering: On a multi-monitor setup, sometimes a dialog will show up on a different monitor from its parent window. This is not desirable.

Answer (score 9):

Have you looked at the `WindowStartupLocation` property for `Window`?

`CenterScreen` places the Window in the center of the screen containing the cursor, which should normally be fine. For example, if a user clicks a button on your Window and a dialog opens, the cursor will still be over the button and thus the dialog will show up in the center of the same Window.

`CenterOwner` places the Dialog in the center of the Window specified as it's owner. Declare the new Window similar to this:

```
MyDialog d = new MyDialog { Owner = parentWindow };
d.ShowDialog();
```

Comment: Not sure where did you get the **Centre** interpretation from my question but in general setting the owner did the trick for what I asked for. `optionsView.Owner = Application.Current.MainWindow;`. and it doesn't use the `System.Windows.Forms` cuz the dialog always follows it's owner in whichever screen it is. :)

Comment: Yeah, I think I got sidetracked and forgot what you were actually asking... Glad to help!

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to add to this the fact that if you start the second dialog maximized, it will default to the main screen.  As a workaround, I set the maximize flag in the OnLoad method.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the dialog to open on the same output screen as the parent form you need to set the `StartPosition`

```
ChildDialog cd = new ChildDialog() { StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterParent };
cd.ShowDialog();
```