# Move the message box only in the application area

Tags: c#, winforms, messagebox, topmost

I have a message box to be displayed and I have set it to top most in C#. When the message box is displayed , I want to move it only in the opened application area and not any where else in the desktop.  Is it possible ??

Comment: Please note that the `visual-studio` tag should only be used for questions about Visual Studio, not code merely written or viewed using it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29023376/how-to-make-a-dialogview-open-up-on-the-same-monitor-as-the-main-window

Comment: Nope . I am already setting the owner. My question is that once we show the message box , it can be moved anywhere on the screen. I want to limit the movement only till its main application.  Is it possible ??

Comment: I don't think so; even a normal Form when shown as Dialog cannont be restricted in its movement. This code `f2.Move += (ss, ee) =>
            {
 f2.Left = Math.Min(Math.Max( f2.Left, Left),  Right - f2.Width);
 f2.Top = Math.Min(Math.Max( f2.Top, Top),  Bottom - f2.Height);
            };` simply fails for a form f2 shown with f2.ShowDialog(); usually makes sense as users should be able to look under the dialog..

Comment: The only type of application that (normally) has windows restricted to being contained within other windows are [MDI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/advanced/multiple-document-interface-mdi-applications). However, even with those it's normal to *not* constrain dialogs using that mechanism and I would strongly suggest you don't re-architect your whole application just to get this behaviour that'll probably *confuse* your users more than any benefit you expect to gain from it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2576220/17034